# multiple submit button in python

Tags: python, html, apache, localhost

I am newbie to python,I have  HTML form for inserting the user name and address into database using python.And have two submit type buttons ,one is add button to add the information into the database and one is delete button to delete the user information .(Python3.4)

HTML code as given below:

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>demo web file python3.2</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wel.css">
</head>  
<body>  
<form action="/cgi-bin/python3.py" method="post">
<label>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"></label><br />
<label>address:<input type="text" name="pass" /></label><br />
<input type="submit" value="add" name="add" />
<input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete" />
</form> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Python code :

```
#!"C:\python34\python.exe"
import cgitb ,cgi
import sys
import mysql.connector
cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()



/*database connection*/

if "add" in form:
    /*code to insert into database*/
elif "delete" in form:
    /* code delete from database*/
else:
    print ("Couldn't determine which button was pressed.")
```

But problem is it's giving the output as "Couldn't determine which button was pressed."

It won't identify  which submit button is pressed.please suggest what wrong in this code and some other solution .

Comment: I'm not familiar with `cgi` but it could be due to the fact that you have the same line twice: `form = cgi.FieldStorage() `

Comment: @user092 can you add an example of what's the value in the form? Add line print form and paste the output.

Comment: I think I got it. Can't proceed without you putting the example outputs

Comment: @AdityaJoshi form takes user name and address